# PHP - Change file name if name already exists

Tags: php, file, rename, edit

i need to change variable data if the 'data name' already exists..

i have this

```
if (file_exists('../../images/produtos/'.$name)){
        $name = '1_'.$name;
    }
```

it is working, if i have a file with the name that is saved in the variable $name, it create a new one with a 1_ before, but i need to check if there is a **1_.$name**, **2_$name** ......  until there is no file with the name saved in variable **$name.**

If i upload a file with name things.png i need to check if there is already a file called things.png, if there is then change a name to 1_things.png, but if there is a file called 1_things.png change the name to 2_things.png etc etc until there is no file with the same name.

PS: I dont want overwrite obv..

Im sorry for my bad english, but i really dont know how to explain this better, hope you guys understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not rename all the files and add a random string or date at the end of the original file name? Eg. piano.png to piano1234.png That way you dont have to worry about duplicate file names.

Comment: @MarioSegura Segura Sorry its $name not $nome, and yes, name is saving a typo.

Comment: @abushahin Thats okay, but how can i check if there is already a piano1, a piano12, etc ? Sorry i am starting :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
if(file_exists('../../images/produtos/'.$name)){
$i = 1;
    while(file_exists('../../images/produtos/'.$i."_".$name)){
    $i++;
    }
$name = $i."_".$name;
}
```